# Extracting links and title from several pages

Tags: python, regex, rss, beautifulsoup

Im trying to build my own rss with downloadlinks

but the rss feed provides only the link to the whole season.

i'm taking that link to the whole season and want to extract the specific downloadlink to the episode itself (uploaded/ul)

this is what ive got so far.
any possibilities to get that working ?!

```
import feedparser, urllib2, re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

episodenliste = ['Game.of.Thrones','Arrow']

episode_link = []
episode_title = []
d = feedparser.parse('http://serienjunkies.org/xml/feeds/episoden.xml')
for post in d.entries:
    if ('DEUTSCH' in post.title) and any (word in post.title for word in episodenliste) and ('720p' in post.title):
        post.title = post.title.replace('[DEUTSCH] ','')
        post.title = re.sub(r'(.*S\d+E\d+)(.*)',r'\1' ,post.title)
        episode_link.append(post.link)
        episode_title.append(post.title)
        print post.title + ": " + post.link + "\n"

for search_title in episode_title:
    for get_dlLink in episode_link:
        page_ = urllib2.Request(get_dlLink)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(page_).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        print search_title
        title = soup.find('strong', text=search_title)
        if title is not None:
            print title
  #          link = title.parent
   #         links = link.find_all('a')
    #        print links
    #        for link2 in links:
     #           url = link2['href']
      #          print url
       #         pattern = 'http:\/\/download\.serienjunkies\.org.*%s_.*\.html' % ul
        #        if re.match(pattern, url):
         #           print url
```

as far as i can tell it works to that point where im searching the page for the title.

it gets to the pages parsed from the rss. but it doesnt find the title.

my idea was:

first find the title and than extract the 'children'/links from it

any help is appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post a relevant part of the feed here? The website has country-specific access rules.

Comment: You may want to break down the program into functions. Then it is much easier to test the single steps in isolation and ask more specific questions here. From a quick glance it should be enough to remove the `[DEUTSCH] ` prefix and search that text, without a regex, on the linked page. Two steps up (`parent` attribute) there is the `<p>` tag which contains the download links for that episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wihout JavaScript enabled the HTML looks quite different:

```html
<p><strong>Arrow.S02E14.Gegen.die.Zeit.German.DD51.Dubbed.DL.720p.iTunesHD.AVC-TVS</strong><br>
<strong>Download:</strong> <a target="_blank" href="http://download.serienjunkies.org/f-55bc328624d93658/fm_tvs-arrow-dd51-ded-dl-7p-ithd-avc-214.html">hier</a> | filemonkey.in<br>
<strong>Download:</strong> <a target="_blank" href="http://download.serienjunkies.org/f-25023a87144345f9/so_tvs-arrow-dd51-ded-dl-7p-ithd-avc-214.html">hier</a> | share-online.biz<br>
<strong>Download:</strong> <a target="_blank" href="http://download.serienjunkies.org/f-3e8ea978a2cf7bda/ul_tvs-arrow-dd51-ded-dl-7p-ithd-avc-214.html">hier</a> | uploaded.to</p>
```

As the title from the RSS feed without the `[DEUTSCH]` prefix is the first text in the paragraph on the page for the series, it can be the basis for searching and extracting the entry. Two elements up there is the `<p>` tag containing all the data for the episode. And that's links followed by the name of the file hoster.

```
import feedparser
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

FEED_URL = 'http://serienjunkies.org/xml/feeds/episoden.xml'


def is_interesting_entry(entry, title_prefix, series_names):
    return (
        entry.title.startswith(title_prefix)
        and any(name in entry.title for name in series_names)
    )


def process_entry(entry, title_prefix):
    if not entry.title.startswith(title_prefix):
        raise ValueError(
            'expected prefix {0!r} not found in {1!r}'.format(
                title_prefix, entry.title
            )
        )
    return (entry.title[len(title_prefix):], entry.link)


def process_feed(feed_url, title_prefix, series_names):
    return (
        process_entry(entry, title_prefix)
        for entry in feedparser.parse(feed_url).entries
        if is_interesting_entry(entry, title_prefix, series_names)
    )


def get_series_soup(url, cache=dict()):
    if url in cache:
        return cache[url]
    else:
        result = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
        cache[url] = result
        return result


def get_download_urls(soup, title):
    title_text = soup.find(text=title)
    if not title_text:
        return dict()
    else:
        return dict(
            (a_tag.next_sibling.strip('| '), a_tag['href'])
            for a_tag in title_text.parent.parent('a')
        )


def main():
    series_names = ['Game.of.Thrones', 'Arrow']
    for title, url in process_feed(FEED_URL, '[DEUTSCH] ', series_names):
        print
        print title
        hoster2url = get_download_urls(get_series_soup(url), title)
        if hoster2url:
            for hoster, download_url in sorted(hoster2url.iteritems()):
                print '{0:>20s}: {1}'.format(hoster, download_url)
        else:
            print '  --- No downloads ---'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

[PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/a7YV3WWD)

```
<item>
        <title>[DEUTSCH] Arrow.S02E14.Gegen.die.Zeit.GERMAN.DUBBED.720p.HDTV.x264-ZZGtv</title>
        <description>[DEUTSCH] Arrow.S02E14.Gegen.die.Zeit.GERMAN.DUBBED.720p.HDTV.x264-ZZGtv</description>
        <pubDate>Fri, 18 Jul 2014 00:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
        <link>http://serienjunkies.org/arrow/arrow-staffel-2-hdtvweb-dl-sd720p1080p/</link>
</item>
```

sorry, didnt know that

```
<p><strong>Arrow.S02E14.Gegen.die.Zeit.German.DD51.Dubbed.DL.720p.iTunesHD.AVC-TVS</strong><br><div id="download_mirrors" class="download_main"><strong>Download:</strong> <a href="http://download.serienjunkies.org/f-3e8ea978a2cf7bda/ul_tvs-arrow-dd51-ded-dl-7p-ithd-avc-214.html" target="_blank" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">uploaded.net</a> <span style="font-size:10px">(best speed) </span><br><strong style="margin-left:14px">Mirrors:</strong> <img src="http://serienjunkies.org/media/img/stream/application_cascade.png" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Mirrors zeigen" onclick="toggle(&quot;Arrow.S02E14.Gegen.die.Zeit.German.DD51.Dubbed.DL.720p.iTunesHD.AVC-TVS&quot;);"><div id="Arrow.S02E14.Gegen.die.Zeit.German.DD51.Dubbed.DL.720p.iTunesHD.AVC-TVS" style="display: none;">
<strong style="margin-left:20px">Mirror:</strong> <a href="http://download.serienjunkies.org/f-55bc328624d93658/fm_tvs-arrow-dd51-ded-dl-7p-ithd-avc-214.html" target="_blank">filemonkey.in</a><br>
<strong style="margin-left:20px">Mirror:</strong> <a href="http://download.serienjunkies.org/f-25023a87144345f9/so_tvs-arrow-dd51-ded-dl-7p-ithd-avc-214.html" target="_blank">share-online.biz</a><br>
</div><div><strong style="margin-left:18px">Usenet:</strong> <a href="http://www.firstload.com/affiliate/log.php?log=50393&amp;fn=Arrow.S02E14.Gegen.die.Zeit.German.DD51.Dubbed.DL.720p.iTunesHD.AVC-TVS" target="_blank">Highspeed Mirror</a></div></div></p>
```

Comment: The HTML looks quite different from downloading the link without a browser or a browser but with JavaScript disabled.